# (Gallerific) Styling and location of the page numbers and arrows for pagination

Tags: jquery, image, gallery, pagination

I would like to move the pagination numbers and "previous" and "Next" links from the navigation block div to their own separate div.
My current navigation div width is only 105 px and and when I go beyond 3 pages the styling of these items gets crowded and they display on top of each other.
I would like the pagination to go hortizonally underneath the main slide image all on a single line.
Also can I replace the "next" and "previous" links with arrows (gifs?)?

Answer (score 1):

i am also still curious how to reach the  page numbering, but at least i found out how to easily set a gif as prev/next page control:

```
nextPageLinkText:  "<img src='http://www.your_next.gif'>",
prevPageLinkText:  "<img src='http://www.your_prev.gif'>",
```

if you find out about the page numbers i am curious to hear from you.

Best JP